# How to use mean value theorem to prove the inequality $|\sin{x}-\sin{y}|\le|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, inequality

How to use mean value theorem to prove the inequality $|\sin{x}-\sin{y}|\le|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$?

So let us set $f(x)=\sin{x}$ then it's differentiable on $(x,y)$ and continuous on $[x,y]$. So there exists $c$ on $(x,y)$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{\sin{x}-\sin{y}}{x-y}$.

Since $\max{(\sin{x}-\sin{y})}$ is $2$ where $|x-y|=\pi\ge2$. So I guess then we make the conclusion.

Could someone check if my thinking is right?

Comment: I meant the conclusion of the mean-value theorem here is that if $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ then $|f(b)-f(a)| < |(b-a)f'(c)|$ where $|f'(c)|$ is the $\max$ for $f'$ on $[a,b]$

Comment: And without the MVT, note that $$|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|=\left|2\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\right|\le |x-y|$$And we are done!

Answer (score 4):

1) $$\frac{\sin x-\sin y}{x-y}=cos(c)$$ where $c \in [y,x]$. ($y < x$)

2) Take absolute value.

3) Use $|\cos c|\le 1$.

4) Multiply with positive $|x-y|$.

Answer (score 1):

No you're wrong. It is not true that $|x-y|=\pi$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ or you must check the inequality for all $x,y$.

Actually you where almost done when you wrote $$f'(c)=\frac{\sin{x}-\sin{y}}{x-y}.$$ You just have to remember that $f'(c) = \cos(c)$ and that $$|\cos(c)|\leq 1$$

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.  You have 
\begin{equation}
|f'(c)| = \bigg|\frac{\sin{x} - \sin{y}}{x-y}\bigg|
\end{equation}
You know that $|f'(c)| \leq 1,$ and the result follows immediately.